# How to fix typescript overload issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using `DateObject` from `react-multi-date-picker` library. I have a typescript error when using it like this:

```
import DatePicker, { DateObject, Calendar } from "react-multi-date-picker";

const [dateToPayAtCalendar, setDateToPayAtCalendar] = useState(
    query?.date_to_pay_at ? query.date_to_pay_at : ""
);


new DateObject(dateToPayAtCalendar).toDate()
```

This is the full error message of typescript overload:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(object: { year: number; month: number; day: number; hour?: number | undefined; minute?: number | undefined; second?: number | undefined; millisecond?: number | undefined; calendar?: Calendar | undefined; locale?: Locale | undefined; format?: string | undefined; ignoreList?: string[] | undefined; }): DateObject', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ year: number; month: number; day: number; hour?: number | undefined; minute?: number | undefined; second?: number | undefined; millisecond?: number | undefined; calendar?: Calendar | undefined; locale?: Locale | undefined; format?: string | undefined; ignoreList?: string[] | undefined; }'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ year: number; month: number; day: number; hour?: number | undefined; minute?: number | undefined; second?: number | undefined; millisecond?: number | undefined; calendar?: Calendar | undefined; locale?: Locale | undefined; format?: string | undefined; ignoreList?: string[] | undefined; }'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(object: { date?: DateType | undefined; calendar?: Calendar | undefined; locale?: Locale | undefined; format?: string | undefined; ignoreList?: string[] | undefined; }): DateObject', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ date?: DateType | undefined; calendar?: Calendar | undefined; locale?: Locale | undefined; format?: string | undefined; ignoreList?: string[] | undefined; }'.
      Type 'string' has no properties in common with type '{ date?: DateType | undefined; calendar?: Calendar | undefined; locale?: Locale | undefined; format?: string | undefined; ignoreList?: string[] | undefined; }'.
  Overload 3 of 4, '(date: DateType): DateObject', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateType'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'DateType'.
        Type 'string[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Date': toDateString, toTimeString, toLocaleDateString, toLocaleTimeString, and 37 more.ts(2769)
```

How can I figure out these kind of typescript overload issues? Where should I look at and whats the flow to find the problem? And how can I fix this exact overload issue?

[image: overload-issue]